# What do I do when I am unable to resolve the configuration for gcc?

Tags: c++11, error-handling

What do you do when the following error pops up;
{Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath: "gcc"}

I have tried looking the error up and it doesn't really help me out.
My code:
`your text`#include 
`your text`using namespace std;
`your text`cout<<"hello"<<endl;